# Menu for items in a listbox?

Tags: winforms, user-interface, contextmenu

I'm not sure what its called or what i should look up. I'm using a listbox and a ContentMenuStrip which i attached with `listBox1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;`

I would like to have items in my listbox right click able and select things like 'remove'. Using what i have now I can click anywhere on the listbox and i apply to results to the currently selected item. Which is confusing and prone to errors.

How do i make right clicks actually map to elements my mouse is over and not show a right click menu when it isnt over an element (empty space in a listbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution (not completely what you requested I know), would be just to make sure an item is selected before allowing the menu to open.

You do this by registering for the `ContextMenuStrip.Opening` event, and cancelling it if no item is selected.

If I think of something more clever I'll update :)

[EDIT]

OK cool, there's a `IndexFromPoint` method on the `ListBox`. You can use it to determine wether the mouse is over an item! Tell me if you need a code sample.

[EDIT2]

OK, OK, couldn't help myself.. here you go:

```
void ContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.IndexFromPoint(listBox1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)) == -1)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: Done, it works as i expected. Now all thats left is figuring out if i could make some kind of shadow to show whats not selected but highlighted

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it worked (didn't try it myself, I only figured it should work). I don't really understand where you want a shadow.. But if you're into playing with the visuals.. you better off using WPF and XAML instead of Winforms..

Comment: I AM using winforms. I never used WPF but i'd like this to work on mono and .NET 3.5. And I don't think I should spend a lot of time learning WPF for one short project. I'll live with these bugs/lessnice things